# Add space between iCarousel items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, carousel, icarousel

I use `iCarousel` in my objective-c application. When I run the application, the iCarousel items have no space between them even if the view where I put the iCarousel has trailing and leading space with the main view of the UIViewController.

Any help please?

Answer (score 9):

Quoting from https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

> iCarouselOptionSpacing
>
> The spacing between item views. This value is multiplied by the item
>   width (or height, if the carousel is vertical) to get the total space
>   between each item, so a value of 1.0 (the default) means no space
>   between views (unless the views already include padding, as they do in
>   many of the example projects).

How to integrate:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    CGFloat result;

    switch(option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
            result = 1.1f; // If the width of your items is 40 e.g, the spacing would be 4 px.
            break;
        default:
            result = value;
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Since it's a delegation method, do not forget to set delegate of the iCarousel instance.

Comment: Please read the question carefully.. User have not asked the space between 2 items of carousel, but space between the Carausel and containerView.  So, here he wants to say that, let i kept carausel inside MainView keeping leading and trailing space as 50 both side. Now when i run the app.. the carousel items moves on the leading and trailing space. Now what if i have kept some other content on both side. but then it overlaps. so, the question is how to limit the carousel view to its bounds only. It should not go out of its bounds.

Comment: @MehulThakkar "...the **iCarousel items** have no space **between** them..."

Comment: Yes i know that.. they dont have space between them.. but question has no any relevance with it. Pleas read again question.. @Lig is not asking for space between items

Comment: @MehulThakkar I think he's saying that "even though the iCarousel view is strecthing (with trailing and leading spaces) the views are not aligning themselves accordingly". Even the question title says "add space between iCarousel items", so I think you're the one who should read the question and the title again.

Answer (score 1):

For swift

```
carouselView.delegate = self

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    switch (option) {
    case .spacing: return 2 // 2 points spacing
        default: return value
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have done following thing, and achieved the purpose that you want.

1. Add `UIView` at the place where you want your carousel.
2. Add `clipsToBounds` to this view,  `view.clipsToBounds = YES`.//important step
3. Add leading and trailing space constraints as much as you want
   to this view.
4. Now add your carousel view inside this view.

Now check by running the app. It Worked?, Add Smile on your face now, :)